# Public IP points to DocumentRoot of vhosts

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04

Just recently got my VPS and domain for a pet project. I setup Apache and PHP, everything works fine until I put my public ip to the URL. It redirects to the `DocumentRoot` of one of my set `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
  ServerName  mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
  <Directory /var/www/mysite>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from mydomain.com
    Allow from www.mydomain.com
  </Directory>
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/me/public/mydomain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/me/public/mydomain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What do I need to adjust so that everytime my public IP is the one inputted on the URL, it will be just redirect to the default `It works! // /var/www/index.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change where global `DocumentRoot` points in `httpd.conf`

```
#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
```

and change the value in `directory`:

```
#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, btw `Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks` what does this actually does?

Comment: `-Indexes` disables directory listing, `+FollowSymLinks` enables [symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink)